# adding facebook login page to android application with cordova plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-login, cordova-plugins, cordova-facebook

hey i have successfully added the facebook login page on my web page but when i am trying to add login page to my phonegap android application it is not working.
please suggest best way to integrate android application with phonegap facebook plugin.i have imported facebook SDK to my app.

Comment: Maybe this could be of some help https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/962eb0a1c07935ff813e28aa9eaa5581f2e10416/README.md

Comment: i have already used that one but it is not working